# tab containing text as a commad line argument in python

Tags: python, split, argparse

I have a script which takes a string containing tabs as input.

`python foo.py --rg @RG\tID:id\tSM:sample\tLB:lib`

But when this argument is parsed (argparse), it's read as `@RGtID:idtSM:sampletLB:lib`

How do I read the string as it is and then split it by tabs ?

Comment: If the tabs are in the `sys.argv` strings, `argparse` wil put them in the relevant namespace attribute without change.  You can then split the string as desired.

Comment: If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea. Try documenting that so someone else can run the program with that bizarre argument specification.

Comment: Hi sorry, may be this will [help](https://gist.github.com/PoisonAlien/11ffc53a98f7cf229f92)

Answer (score 1):

Most command-line shells will simply take a escaped character (`\x`, where `x` is `t` in your case), and pass it on literally, that is, forgive any special meaning it may have had, if at all.

In the case of "regular" characters (such as `t`), the escape sequence is in effect a redundant operation. For those characters, escaping them makes no difference.

On Unix(-like) platforms, this can be a solution:

```
$ echo -ne '"@RG\tID:id\tSM:sample\tLB:lib"' | xargs python foo.py --rg
```

Where...

- `echo -ne ... |`: Take all its arguments and output them to the standard output. `-n` means "don't output the trailing newline" (actually not necessary here), and `-e` means "interpret escape characters" (this is what translates `\t` into a real horizontal tabulator character). The `|` (pipe) means "instead of sending the output of this program to the shell's standard output (usually the terminal), send it to the standard input of the command after the `|` instead!"
- `xargs python foo.py --rg`: will call program `python` with arguments `foo.py` and `--rg`, plus whatever arguments it interprets from the standard input. If any given argument is between double quotations (such as `"@RG\tID..."`), then the whole thing is passed on literally as a single argument, as would the shell.

**Edit**: If you don't mind having portability issues, in Bash... (thanks to @metatoaster in the comments)

```
$ python foo.py --rg $'@RG\tID\:id\tSM\:sample\tLB\:lib'
```

Will achieve the same effect

I hope this has led some light on you!

Comment: Alternatively, in bash, `python foo.py --rg $'@RG\tID\:id\tSM\:sample\tLB\:lib'`

Comment: Thank you both. Above method works perfectly. But I dont want to use $ for certain reasons. Instead I ended up putting input string in quotes (as above but no $) and splitting with `'\\t'.`    Maybe its not so elegant way of doing this, but for now its doing the job.